# Greasemonkey script to remove parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress, greasemonkey

I have this URL:

```
http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/this-is-an-image_0120(pp_w820_h548).jpg
```

I want delete a parameter from the URL to look like this:

```
http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/this-is-an-image_0120.jpg
```

How is it possible with Greasemonkey?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    var elements = links[i];
    elements.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(pp_w820_h548)/gi, '');
}
```

I want also the width and height numbers will be unknown variables. Sometimes the images are png, so deleting everything after the (, and adding ".jpg" again to the end not the best solution.

SORRY! I meant for targeting img element, not the a. So this is an image, not a link.

Also pp need to be in there, because I only want to remove on the prophoto WP blogs.

So, this is it:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    var images = links[i];
    images.src= images.src.replace(/\(pp_w\d+_h\d+\)/gi, '');
}
```

UPDATE

The script only works with images which is near to viewport. Lazyloaded elements on the page still using the plus strings in url.

Is it possible with Greasemonkey to phisically change the HTML, not just in DOM?

Comment: As for the regex: You need to escape `(` and `)`. digits are written as `[0-9]+` Escaping are done by using a backslash (`\ `) `\(escaped parenthese`.

Comment: @user1442219 what do you mean change the the html not just the dom? the html *is* the dom. It is replacing the sources for images that are there from the beginning, correct? You could always add a timeout as the simplest solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    var a = links[i];
    a.href= a.href.replace(/\(pp_w\d+_h\d+\)/gi, '');
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/houp0qv0/

Comment: Sorry, I meant for targeting the img element, not the a. Sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't know what's going to be inside the parentheses (for example, if the `pp_` prefix may change), you can use:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.src = link.src.replace(/\(.+\)/gi, '');
}
```

Or even:

```
link.src = link.src.replace(/\([a-zA-Z\d]+_[a-zA-Z\d]+_[a-zA-Z\d]+\)/gi, '');
```